# VB.net Label with sliding text from left to right

Tags: vb.net, text, label

The text that I want to show in my label is quite long, thus I thought about making the text sort of slide inside the label from the left to the right.

Is this possible in VB.net?

Comment: This is an interesting question. As far as I know, this is not a default behavior you can switch on and off. You'll have to implement it yourself if you really want it.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990288/7444103) (using a TextBox). Or the string should scroll to the left after it has already being assigned to the Label (the Label's text is already partially visible)? So, maybe, after a delay or some other event (after the Form is shown, for example)?

Comment: @Jimi no, the text will already be assigned and the answer by Lectere kind of does what I need, however it crashes after a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can;

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim BigStr As String = "         this is a very big string, and I want to slide it ya ya ya          "
    Dim Pointer As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = BigStr.Substring(Pointer, 5)
        Pointer = Pointer + 1
        Pointer = Pointer Mod (BigStr.Length - 6)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Don't forget to enable your timer

Comment: This works for the first few seconds, but once the text has slid to the end my application crashes throwing error "Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

Comment: This, as in my code above, works 100%. It's your adaptation that's wrong. I've tested my code, and everything works, and it jumps back to the start and scrolls again. You need a big black space at the end of your string, and play with the numbers 5 and 6 in the code sample above. Read the error message, and then read here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Right, but using the provided code makes the visible part of the text extremely tiny. You can only see like 5 letters a time, which makes it extremely hard to actually understand the text

Comment: I'm amazed by the lack of initiative from your site. I deliver code, EXACTLY what you described. Then you wrongly accuse me that my code contains errors, while it doesn't contain errors. You adaptation is probably bad. I advice you how to continue, but to actually read your error message and act upon it is to much to ask. I'm not helping you any further, this is not a coding service. If you really are unable to understand this material, maybe coding is not for you, and you should hire someone to program for you...

Comment: No need to be rude. Some people here are really friendly and helpful, you seem to be somewhat different. Anyway, thanks for the code, ill try asking some friends who are - like me - still LEARNING to code.

Comment: You are rude, saying that my code has errors, that's simply not true. And yes my aim is to get you to learn coding, not do everything for you. You're showing zero initiative, you did not write a single line of code in your request. You did not described what you tried. You just want others to code for you. That's not how you learn. Some people actually show some intelligence and can actually read error messages and understand how to get around them, you seem to be somewhat different. You're not showing interest in learning, you're showing interest in copy-pasting code made by others.