# How to delete last entering character(s) if TextBox width bigger than 75

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

1- Copy and paste following code into **MainWindow.xaml** file.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Hello people"/>
    <Label x:Name="LabelForTestingNeeds1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,100,0,0" Content="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TextBox1}"/>
    <Label x:Name="LabelForTestingNeeds2" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,150,0,0" Content="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=TextBox1}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

2- Copy and paste following code into **code behind** file.

```vb
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.ActualWidth > 75 Then
            'Delete last entering character(s)
            'Or prevent entering a new character(s)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

3- Run this project and add some character(s) into TextBox1.

**How to delete last entering character(s) if TextBox1 width bigger than 75?**

or

**How to prevent entering characters(s) into TextBox1 if TextBox1 width bigger than 75?**

> So this question is about textbox width in pixels.

Comment: Do you mean the to limit the max number of chars that can be entered or the max **width** of the control? I think you're referring to the number of chars. Anyway, the TextBox control has MaxLength, MaxWidth, MaxHeight, MaxLines properties, where MaxLength is the maximum number of chars the control can accept.

Comment: @Jimi I have already tried to use MaxLength property but MaxLength property is not okey for me. For example `Jimi` is consist of 4 characters, `Dann` is consist of 4 characters. But `Jimi` length and `Dann` length is not equal. Because every character in the alphabet has diiferent width.The `w` is the widest character, the `i` is the narrowest character.

Comment: Ah, do you mean the Text length in pixels? [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext) can be used to measure the string length in pixels. Or [TextRenderer.Measuretext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext). It depends on what method you're more confortable with. You could measure the string and remove the last char entered if the string length is greater than a value.

Comment: Yes I mean the Text length in pixels.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990288/7444103). Both methods are used to measure a string length in pixels.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for links you have posted but none of above links solves my problem.

Comment: Well, maybe if you explain why those methods can't solve your problem, it would be more clear what the problem is. Do you mean you cannot get a correct measure of the text or you don't know how to use that measure?

Comment: It is not possible to fit formatted text size to Textbox width. Measuring of formatted text is different than measuring textbox width.

Comment: Just a thought, but how about switching to a fixed-width font?

Comment: @video.baba  No, font size must be stable.

Comment: It's certainly possible. You should show what you're measuring and what you're comaparing this measure to. Note that there's a difference between the `TextBox.Width` and the `.ViewportWidth` values.

Answer (score 1):

This is the text changed event so you cannot prevent the entering of chars, but this should work

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.Text.length > 75 Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 75)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your answer is not okey because every character in the alphabet has different width.The `w` is the widest character, the `i` is the narrowest character.

Comment: Length != width length is the character count

Answer (score 0):

The measurements of a drawn text depends not just on the characters used as you comment, but also on the font type and the font's size.

There is a class specifically designed to calculate this, namely `FormattedText` in the `System.Windows.Media` namespace.

Just create a new object with information about the text to be drawn, its font, and other properties:

```
var formattedText = new System.Windows.Media.FormattedText("my text", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("MyFont"), 32, Brushes.Black);
var width = formattedText.Width; //use to limit or do whatever
```