# Updating a label using a for statement (typewriter effect)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

I'm developing a game in Windows Forms (.NET-framework), and I want to add a typewriter effect to the text I'm displaying (*so that it displays letter by letter*). I'm using a for-loop for this. The text is displayed in a label.

I have 2 variables. 1 that holds all the text, and one that holds the text that needs to be printed out in the loop:

```
public string FullText;
private string CurrentText = "";
```

The label that I want to update with the loop is called: `LblTextBottom`

This is the method that gets executed when I click on the appropriate button:

```
public void TypeWriterEffect()
{
    for(int i=0; i < FullText.Length; i++)
    {
         CurrentText = FullText.Substring(0, i);

         LblTextBottom.Text = CurrentText;

         Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

This is the code that is activated when I click on the button to run the TypeWriterEffect method:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FullText = LblTextBottom.Text;
    ShowText();
}
```

It updates the Label, and the code works, but I don't see it updating in real time (the text doesn't get displayed letter by letter). I've tried using separate threads to update the control, but I didn't get that to work.

Ofcourse, I wouldn't be here if this code was working. But I don't know why it won't update. So any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**P.s:** [This is what I'm looking for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVh4nH8Mayg), but ofcourse without the UnityEngine classes and namespace (can't use those).

**EDIT:** Forgot to tell that when a button is clicked, a new string of text is loaded into the `LblTextBottom`, from a different .cs file.

Comment: Make `TypeWriterEffect()` async and change `Thread.Sleep(10);` to `await Task.Delay(10);`. I suggest you append chars to a StringBuilder. You don't need `CurrentText`.

Comment: A 10ms wait (`Thread.Sleep(10)`) is too low for people to notice. I suggest playing with this number until you see the desired effect. Maybe starting at about 500ms or 750ms

Comment: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990288/7444103) of the result with a delay of 100ms (note that it's for WPF, some methods names might sound unfamiliar, but you just need the `Task.Delay()` part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write it generically, then you can have multiple typewriters going at the same time:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;

    await TypeWriterEffect("This is some text to be `typed`...", LblTextBottom, 100);

    button1.Enabled = true;
}

private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Enabled = false;

    await TypeWriterEffect("Look mom, we're running at the same time!!!", label2, 200);

    button2.Enabled = true;
}

public Task TypeWriterEffect(string txt, Label lbl, int delay)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= txt.Length; i++)
        {
            lbl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                lbl.Text = txt.Substring(0, i);
            });                    
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay); ;
        }
    });            
}
```

Producing:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't actually display all characters on label. For loop should be `i <= txt.length`.

Comment: Lol...how did I never notice that?  =)  Edited the code. Thanks for the fix!