# How to make auto-move the text that a Datagridview's cell contains

Tags: c#, winforms

In HTML language, it exists the tag "marquee" which allows a text to move automatically.
Does it exist any way on Visual C# Datagridview that could have the same effect?
The reason is that, for example, I have a 25 pixel column that contains a very long text (let's say about 255 chars) and it doesn't fit on the screen. There are a lot of more columns which already fits all the screen.

The users haven't got a mouse, so I have to find a way to the users can read all the information on each column and each row in order to read all the content, so it would be a great solution having a "marquee" effect on some cells.

If you have any idea or you know a function which allows that, please share it.

I have Visual Studio 2019. The project is a .Net Windows Form on C# on .Net Framework 4.8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sadly not and the `<marquee>` tag is also [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee), it should not be used for production. And to be honest, i think adding something like it to a dense datagrid, would give you eye cancer

Comment: I normally use a Tooltip if the text can be too large.

Comment: I agree with Patrick that having a marquee effect on several cells at the same time is probably very hard to follow. But you can make it activate on mouse-over and stop on mouse-out, so only one cell content is scrolling at any given time. You cannot easily scroll the text itself, but you can add a separate text control (perhaps a label) to the form inside a container, and in the mouse-enter event, you give it the same location and dimensions of the cell, copy the cell's text to it, bring it on top of the grid, show it, and start scrolling it. And on mouse-out event, simply hide it.

Comment: How can a User select the current Cell and the text to scroll? You cannot scroll Text on a Cell 25 pixels wide. Scrolling the text is pretty simple, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990288/7444103), for example (that's a WPF TextBox, but it's the same in WinForms, just somewhat more *manual*), but you need some *space* to do that.